# Plot Piecewise does not work with NDSolve, works with ordinary function

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, piecewise

How to join output from NDSolve with another function in a plot, using Piecewise or something else? I could join a simple function with another in a plot, but could not do it for the output.

MWE:

```
Clear[sol, f]

sol = NDSolve[{f'[x] == f[x], f[1] == 1}, f[x], x]

Plot[{Piecewise[{{f[x] /. sol, 0 <= x <= 1}, {0.9, 1 < x <=2}}],
Piecewise[{{0.7*x, 0 <= x <= 1}, {0.5, 1 < x <= 2}}]}, {x, 0, 2}]
```

Mathematica v9, Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit, Dell PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using First[] around the solution solved the problem:

```
Plot[{Piecewise[{{f[x] /. First[sol], 0 <= x <= 1}, {0.9, 
 1 < x <= 2}}], Piecewise[{{0.7*x, 0 <= x <= 1}, {0.5, 1 < x <= 2}}]}, {x, 0, 2}]
```

Happy to delete the question as I don't think the answers would help others, but I'm getting an error when I try.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the error messages you get,

> NDSolve::ndlim: Range specification x is not of the form {x, xend} or
>   {x, xmin, xmax}. >>

What does that mean?  Ask for help on `NDSolve` and you can see you didn't use the function properly,

```
?NDSolve
```

[image]

So add a range, here just use the range you are plotting over,

```
Clear[sol, f]

sol = NDSolve[{f'[x] == f[x], f[1] == 1}, f[x], {x, 0, 2}]

Plot[{Piecewise[{{f[x] /. sol, 0 <= x <= 1}, {0.9, 1 < x <= 2}}], 
  Piecewise[{{0.7*x, 0 <= x <= 1}, {0.5, 1 < x <= 2}}]}, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Your plot is still missing the second Piecewise part. But thank you for pointing out a different error.